# Easy way to manage multiple JS files?

Tags: javascript

I have a server running on a LEMP stack.

I have multiple pages and multiple different JS files required on them. Say I have the JS files JS1.js JS2.js JS3.js, page1.html might require 1 and 2, page 2.html might require 2 and 3.

Is there an easy way to manage this? I know it's bad practice to have multiple JS files so is there a program that will combine all the required ones for the page and send that out? I know I can just manually do it, but it becomes a pain when I need to edit one of the files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of existing js bundlers such as Browserify or Webpack